# How to add jms queue with maven?

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface, maven-plugin

How can I execute a .cli commands with maven? What maven plugin helps me into doing this?

I want to execute some cli commands in the pre-integration-test phase.

The commands which I want to run is

```
jms-queue add --queue-address=ProcessingEngine --entries=java:global/jms/ProcessingEngine
```

And the plugin that I am using is

> wildfly-maven-plugin

The full configuration that I use is

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Alpha11</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-wildfly</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <startupTimeout>420</startupTimeout>
                <jbossHome>${env.WILDFLY_HOME}</jbossHome>
                <serverConfig>standalone-full.xml</serverConfig>
                <javaOpts>
                    <javaOpts>-DIGNITE_HOME=${env.TEMP}</javaOpts>
                    <javaOpts>-Xms512m</javaOpts>
                    <javaOpts>-Xmx4094m</javaOpts>
                    <javaOpts>${ITargLine}</javaOpts>
                    <javaOpts>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n</javaOpts>
                    <javaOpts>-Dwkfs.local.configuration.file=${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/wkfs-external.properties</javaOpts>
                </javaOpts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jms-queues</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute-commands</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <commands>
                    <executeCommands>
                    <!-- Create Processing Engine queue -->
                    jms-queue add --queue-address=ProcessingEngine --entries=java:global/jms/ProcessingEngine
                    </executeCommands>
                    <executeCommands>
                        <!-- Create Processing Engine notification queue -->
                        jms-topic add --topic-address=ProcessingEngineNotification --entries=java:global/jms/ProcessingEngineNotification
                    </executeCommands>
                </commands>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I get this exception

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha11:execute-commands
>   (start-jms-queues) on project integration-test: Execution
>   start-jms-queues of goal
>   org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha11:execute-commands
>   failed: Command 'jms-queue add --queue-address=ProcessingEngine
>   --entries=java:global/jms/ProcessingEngine,java:/jms/myApp/ProcessingEngine'
>   is invalid. The command is not available in the current context (e.g.
>   required subsystems or connection to the controller might be
>   unavailable). -> [Help 1]

If I use the command line and manually set the JAVA_OPTS to use the standalone-full.xml, start the server again and connect to it, then run the add jms query from command line, it works.

Comment: Is there a way you are already doing this(executing a `.cli`) in `java`?

Comment: no, i have not done it already. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to add a jms queue using `add-resource` goal

```
                 <execution>
                    <id>add-jms-queue</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <address>subsystem=messaging,hornetq-server=default,jms-queue=ProcessingEngine</address>
                                <properties>
                                    <durable>true</durable>
                                    <entries>!!["java:global/jms/ProcessingEngine"]</entries>
                                </properties>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <address>subsystem=messaging,hornetq-server=default,jms-topic=ProcessingEngineNotification</address>
                                <properties>
                                    <durable>true</durable>
                                    <entries>!!["java:global/jms/ProcessingEngineNotification"]</entries>
                                </properties>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```